# Nginx "log_format" directive is not allowed here

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am getting error

"log_format" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"

nginx.conf

```
server {
   ---
    --
        log_format  custom  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
         access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log custom if=$logme;

}
```

What is missing?

Comment: The [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format) states that the directive must be in `http` context (which is the outer most block). You could move the statement above the line beginning `server {`

Answer (score 1):

To understand what `Context:    http` [documentation means](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format)

```bash
events {
    # ...
}

http {
    upstream name {
       # ...
    }

    # HERE
    log_format custom  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    server {
       # ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you should specify `http` under the `server` so it should look like:

```
server {

  http {
    # your server configurations
  }
  
  # The rest configurations
   log_format  custom  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
   access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log custom if=$logme;
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. Have a look at the comment of [Richard Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75658528/nginx-log-format-directive-is-not-allowed-here#comment133480195_75658528) to see the correct answer.